# Summarize parts of Excel-table

Tags: vba, excel, summarization

I've got a question at VBA in Microsoft Excel Office.

There is a table with two rows (head to bottom) and thousands of lines.

In the 1st row there are strings containing names of software companies like Adobe.

In the 2nd row there are strings containing names of products of the companies in row 1 like Acrobat Reader 11.

So what I want is, that in row 2 strings like: "Acrobat Reader 11" and "Acrobat Reader 10" will be summarized to "Acrobat Reader" is this possible?
It's not only Version Numbers also, "Office Word" "Office Excel" to "Office".

Can you help me? By the way I'm a noob in VBA and Excel.

Greets

Comment: What should be the criteria for merging your data? Find common substrings or group by just company? Do you mean two columns and thousands of lines?? (line and row are synonyms in excel)

Comment: Oh sorry, yes I mean 2 columns and thousands of lines.
My criteria should be merging like: when the first 2 words in column 2 in different lines are the same, it should merge them. That will lower the number of lines in a big way I think and I think without manual editing it's not possible to do it perfect.

Comment: Without VBA, you can use `Data->Text to Columns` to split the product column into a separate column for each "word" (split it `delimited` and then use `space` as the delimiter).  This will give a bunch of columns.  You can then delete all the columns except for the first 2.  With those 2 columns you can then sort and filter (or use `Data->Remove Duplicates`) to pare down the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split your second column into multiple columns first as commented well. (in Excel 2010: data tab - text to columns - delimited - delimiters: space) - your data will look like: column A: company, columns B-C product name, delete the other columns

After that you should add a column which tells you whether second word of product name (e.g. Reader) is used in multiple rows , so you can group on it, or it's unique: `=COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,C:C,C2)`, let's call this new column unique.

Now you need another column to merge first two words if second one isn't unique: `=B2&IF(D2>1," "&C2,"")`

And finally just create a pivot with columns A and E.